# Regexp_Like to get exact string match

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i get exact string match by using REGEXP_LIKE. When i use the below sql, it always returns 'True' when i try to match for 'SETID_EMPL_CLASS' as whole string.

```
select 'True'
from Dual
where REGEXP_like ('SETID_EMPL_CLASS', '(^|;)' || upper('ethnic_grp_cd|empl_type|full_part_time|comp_frequenc|empl_class'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the full string match (not just a part of a string) with `regexp_like` you should add `^` and `$` to the set of alternatives:

```
select 'True'
from Dual 
where REGEXP_like ('SETID_EMPL_CLASS', upper('^(ethnic_grp_cd|empl_type|full_part_time|comp_frequenc|empl_class)$'));
```